# Mysterious spacing or padding in elements in a VStack in a ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I don't understand why I have extraneous vertical spacing between elements in a `ForEach` that is inside a `VStack` that is inside a `ScrollView` when using a `GeometryReader` to render a custom horizontal separator line.

```
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(self.model1.elements, id: \.self) { element in
                VStack.init(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    //                    Text("test") // image 3: works correctly
                    //                        .background(Color.blue)
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Path { path in
                            path.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: 0))
                            path.addLine(to: .init(x: geometry.size.width, y: 0))
                        }
                        .strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 1, dash: [1,2]))
                    }
//                    .frame(maxHeight: 1) // image 2: uncommenting this line doesn't fix the spacing
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .background(Color.blue)

                    HStack {
                        Text("\(element.index+1)")
                            .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                            .frame(width: 32, alignment: .trailing)
                        Text(element.element)
                            .font(.system(.caption, design: .monospaced))
                            .frame(maxWidth:nil)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth:nil)
                    .background(Color.green)
                }
                .border(Color.red)
            }
        }
```

The above code produces this:
[image]

With `.frame(maxHeight: 1)` the blue padding is gone, but still there is white space between the consecutive `HStack`s.
[image]

I want the vertical spacing to be like in this image, ie 0.  This image is achieved by uncommenting the `Text("test")` source, and commenting the `GeometryReader` code.
[image]

I'm using Xcode `11.3.1 (11C504)`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I understand your ultimate goal, it's to have each row bordered above by a dotted line, with no padding between them, like this:

[image: rows separated by red dotted lines]

In that case, IMO you should put the lines in a background. For example:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(self.elements, id: \.self) { element in
            HStack {
                Text("\(element.index+1)")
                    .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                    .frame(width: 32, alignment: .trailing)
                Text(element.element)
                    .font(.system(.caption, design: .monospaced))
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Color.green
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Path { path in
                            path.move(to: .zero)
                            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: 0))
                        }
                        .strokedPath(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, dash: [1,2]))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

A key point is that ScrollView is not a vertical stacking container. It just takes its content and makes it scrollable. Its content in your code is a ForEach, which generates views; it doesn't really intend to lay them out. So when you combine a ScrollView with a ForEach, nothing is really in charge of placing the views the way you want. To stack views vertically, you want a VStack.

You can apply this to your structure just as well, but adding another VStack, and get the same results:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 0) { // <---
        ForEach(self.elements, id: \.self) { element in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Path { path in
                        path.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: 0))
                        path.addLine(to: .init(x: geometry.size.width, y: 0))
                    }
                    .strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 1, dash: [1,2]))
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(height: 1)

                HStack {
                    Text("\(element.index+1)")
                        .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                        .frame(width: 32, alignment: .trailing)
                    Text(element.element)
                        .font(.system(.caption, design: .monospaced))
                        .frame(maxWidth:nil)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .background(Color.green) // <-- Moved
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple addition of `(spacing: 0)` just solved a good hour of futile debugging. This is a life saver

Comment: Thank you so much for spacing: 0! It is so weird and frustrating behaviour.

Answer (score 14):

The spacing is generated by `VStack`.

When creating a `VStack`, add the parameter for ***spacing*** and set it to ***0***.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
  Element1()
  Element2()
  Element3()
  Element4()
}
```

[VStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack)

The same spacing property is available for `HStack`, `LazyVStack` and `LazyHStack`

Answer (score 4):

###### ✅ The undesired ***white space*** issue

The issue is the displacement of the `VStack` and the `ForEach`:

So this:

```
ForEach(self.model1.elements, id: \.self) { element in
   VStack.init(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) { //  move line this up
      ...
   } 
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
VStack.init(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) { 
   ForEach(self.model1.elements, id: \.self) { element in
      ...
   }  
}
```

the `spacing: 0` that is mentioned by the OP will get rid of the spacing.

---

###### And about the actual need:

You just need to add a simple `overlay` to create the desired dashed line. So the entire code would be as simple as this:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { element in
            HStack {
                Text("\(element.index+1)")
                    .font(.system(.caption, design: .rounded))
                    .frame(width: 32, alignment: .trailing)
                Text(element.element)
                    .font(.system(.caption, design: .monospaced))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        .overlay {
            Rectangle().stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 2, dash: [1,2]))
                .mask(alignment: .top) { Rectangle().frame(height: 2) }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else can be removed.

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank you!